# MANOVA application

Tags: regression, machine-learning, manova

Need to check whether it is mandatory to have at least one continuous DVs in MANOVA, also does sample size of 2 groups matters much, i am planning to check whether recruits from campus or off-campus have significant difference in 4 selected DVs. sample size for campus is 23K & off campus is 14K?

Please advise accordingly, can any other statistical technique be applied here say, MLR?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it mandatory to have at least one continuous DVs in MANOVA?

Yes, Manova is a multivariate technique. You need to have more than one continuous response variables (and no categorical response).

2. Does sample size of 2 groups matters much?

You should have an adequate sample size. Although the larger your sample size, the better; for MANOVA, you need to have more cases in each group than the number of dependent variables you are analysing.
In your case, you've large sample size, so it's not an issue.